# Generic wrapper function that calls a method of an object by a given key

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to write a generic wrapper function called `foo` that takes an object `o` and a key `k` plus some `args` and calls `o[k](...args)` in a type-safe manner with inferred return type.

Here is an example:

```
const obj = {
   a: 1,
   b: true,
   c: (name: string) => `Hello, ${name}.`,
   d: (name: string) => `Goodbye, ${name}.`,
};

const result = foo(obj, 'c', 'Peter');
// typeof result === 'string'
console.log(result); // Hello, Peter.
```

Here is what I cooked up so far:

```
function foo<
  Args extends any[],
  Return,  
  Target,
  Key extends keyof {
    [K in keyof Target as Target[K] extends ((...args: Args) => any) ? K : never]: Target[K]
  }
>(target: Target, key: Key, ...args: Args): Return
{
  // typeof method === 'Target[Key]'
  const method = target[key];
  
  // This expression is not callable. Type 'unknown' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
  return method(...args);
}

// Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)
const result = foo(obj, 'c');
```

Is it possible to express such a wrapper function in TypeScript and if so, then how would you go about it?

---

**Edit:**

I took Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's answer and adjusted it to give me the correct return type:

```
type FunctionKeys<Target> = keyof {
  [K in keyof Target as Target[K] extends ((...args: any) => any) ? K : never]: Target[K]
}

function foo<
Target extends Record<Key, (...args: any) => any>,
Key extends FunctionKeys<Target>,
>(...[target, key, ...args]: [Target, Key, ...Parameters<Target[Key]>]) {
  const method = target[key];
  return method(...args) as ReturnType<Target[Key]>;
}
```

I could have also adjusted Tobias S.' answer the same way, but I found that using the tuple generated better compiler errors. Here is an example:

```
const obj = {
  greet: (name: string) => `Hello, ${name}.`,
};

// Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)
fooTitian(obj, 'greet');

// Argument of type '{ greet: (name: string) => string; }' is not assignable // to parameter of type 'Record<"greet", () => any>'.
//   Types of property 'greet' are incompatible.
//     Type '(name: string) => string' is not assignable to type '() => any'.ts(2345)
fooTobias(obj, 'greet');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `Args` parameter, you ca just type the rest parameter using `Parameters`. You can also use a tuple to convince Typescript that the parameters are tied together

```
type FunctionKeys<Target> = keyof {
    [K in keyof Target as Target[K] extends ((...args: any) => any) ? K : never]: Target[K]
  }
function foo<
  Target extends Record<Key, (...args: any) => any>,
  Key extends FunctionKeys<Target>,
>(...[target, key, ...args]: [Target, Key, ...Parameters<Target[Key]>]): ReturnType<Target[Key]> {
  // typeof method === 'Target[Key]'
  const method = target[key];
  return method(...args);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-boDA6-QlLA0B8QBwEIh1GbgGb1AAibejnBT2Cz+fN11LldIdeb9QABlHME19loIFoQA)

Comment: Tobias' solution seems to do it without the tuple, but is there a footgun if we don't have it? For instance, unions and explicit type arguments?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The way he does it it inverse to me. He uses the key and the args as the inference site and type the object relative to those. I use the object as the inference site, and type the key and the args relative to the object. The main problem with TobiasS's approach is that we loose code completion for the key and the argument names. Either solution is valid from a type system perpective, I just prefer the DX of the second one

Answer (score 1):

You could compose the generic types of the function like this:

```
function foo<
  Target extends Record<Key, (...args: Args) => any>,
  Args extends unknown[],
  Key extends PropertyKey
>(target: Target, key: Key, ...args: Args): ReturnType<Target[Key]> 
{
  const method = target[key];
  return method(...args);
}
```

The magic happens in the constraint of `Target`. We constrain it to be a `Record` where the key is of type `Key`. The value type is a function with `Args` as its parameter types. The return type of the function is typed using the utility-type `ReturnType`.

Using a generic type for `Arg` also allows for type-safety inside the function implementation. This would be errors:

```
function foo<
  Target extends Record<Key, (...args: Args) => any>,
  Args extends unknown[],
  Key extends PropertyKey
>(target: Target, key: Key, ...args: Args): ReturnType<Target[Key]> {
  const method = target[key];

  
  method("abc")
  //     ~~~~~ Argument of type '[string]' is not assignable to 
  //           parameter of type 'Args'

  return 123
  //     ~~~ Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<Target[Key]>'
}
```

This is how calling the function would look like:

```
// valid
const result = foo(obj, "c", "Peter");

// invalid
foo(obj, "a")
foo(obj, "c", 123)
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AoRiAqBDAJwHMBTKREgDyhLABMBnRAJRIjgLrQGkSBPADSIAFADpxhIgwBciAILEGASkQBeAHyI8YPuoFZ5iitVqNE4ANZg4AdzABtALr7svPsZr0mABQJwADiQEUHxuGOrCUJJksvjEZEIW-LJuQuKikjKGUkqyrFAgBGA4fIFocaRQ9m6OmgDeBuxgDOQAtmQAFnB0aohR8VVJfI4A3BgGAPQTiAgANu4KUogQ2ogARiSI-ngMDCQ9UHB9HZugkLAIBu1QXXTCAER4axD3SuPYBGSFSNe3YhKKJRjAC+4yaLRmawAVr0Gtg8LIAIwudayKAEEAkFEQWTCMB4dqyFoEGBgIgqDSIAAGAAkSLNZnAhAASOr49rA0RUlF0XHskiyMAgVobAgUzRUgDiqDoaz4WMQrP5nO5GGBYwwU0QADc8LMYHQMODyJ8GCBZuRVMhUMI4NChPcXg7vGQgq8xlrsIgAHoAfmWCAhpvNUCJ6NJRHGWtJuv1hpQcFt9sQj1eGATSahDqdiERACYAMxvcZGwNwWYkUSMojCYMWoEYIA)